# Trigger Angular animation on form error

Tags: angular, animation, angular5, angular-forms, angular-animations

I am trying to give the user a visual feedback when he tries to send a form with a wrong input. Therefore I want to animate the input field when he tries to send the form if it contains errors.

**The animation in the ts file:**

```js
trigger('error', [
      transition('* => *', useAnimation(shake)),
      ]),
```

**The form in the html file:**

```html
<mat-form-field [@error]="error">
```

Is it possible to trigger this animation each time the user tries to send the form and it contains errors?

[**StackBlitz example (Updated with solution)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-list-form-animation?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)

As you can see the shake animation is played in the beginning and then not anymore.

**SOLUTION:**

From the below answer i changed the order of setting the `onAddErrAnim` variable. Now `onAddErrAnim` is set to `false` first and then the `if` statement is called inside a `setTimout` with 0 milliseconds. Now the user can call `onAdd()` every millisecond and the animation is played to the end (if no new animation is triggered).

```js
onAdd() {
  this.onAddErrAnim = false;

  setTimeout( () => {

    if (this.myFormControl.invalid) {
      this.onAddErrAnim = true;
      return;
    } else {
      this.myArray.unshift([this.inputExample]);
    }

  }, 0 )

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your [code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-to-list-top-animation-94toihu-cvby8s?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html):

```
<div class="example-container" >
  <mat-form-field 
    floatPlaceholder="never" 
    class="input-box" 
    style="width: 100%" 
    (keyup.enter)="onAdd()"
    [@error]="myFormControl.invalid">
```

`@error` will be triggered when form is invalid.

> animation is still called when loading the page. how do i avoid that?

[CODE EXAMPLE 2 (UPDATED)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-to-list-top-animation-2).

> and also I want the animation to be triggered only on the onAdd()
>   function

I created an animationState property in the component class:

```
animateError = 'false';
```

and bound it to the `[@error]` trigger. Depending from state changes, it will trigger the according animation.

From `false => true` inside the template file:

```
 ...
 transition('false => true', useAnimation(shake)),
```

Inside the template:

```
[@error]="animateError">
```

When the `onAdd()` function is called, it updates the state by validation of `myFormControl`:

```
    onAdd() {
    if (this.myFormControl.invalid) {
      this.animateError = 'true';
       // after animation is done, restore the initial state
       setTimeout(() => {
          this.animateError = false;
       }, 500);

      return;
    } else {
      this.animateError = 'false';
    }
    console.log(this.myFormControl);
    this.myArray.unshift([this.inputExample]);

  }
```

**UPDATE 19.03.2018:**

Little improved code example, by replacing animation state's `string` variable to `boolean`:

```
 trigger('error', [
      state('0', style({})),
      state('1', style({})),
      transition('0 => 1', useAnimation(shake)),
    ]),
```

...

```
 animateError = 'false'; =>  animateError = false;
```

> shouldn't there be a more performant way to trigger the animation
>   without saving a boolean in a variable?

In this case, no. When using custom **animation states** we need to save state value somewhere. It may be in component class, data model class... Because in your specific case, we need to manually control animation(animation need to be triggered **only** when `onAdd()` function is called).

Comment: the animation is still called when loading the page. how do i avoid that? And also I want the animation to be triggered only on the `onAdd()` function

Comment: @NightTrain, added code example 2 for your first question

Comment: @NightTrain, answered to your second question

Comment: shouldn't there be a more performant way to trigger the animation without saving a boolean in a  variable?

Comment: i tried to set the `animateError` to false before the `if` instead of using the timeout function inside the `onAdd()` function. Why does that not work?

Comment: @NightTrain, I think this operation(2 or more state changes) can't be done in one `digest cycle`, therefore we use `setTimeout` to run it in next cycle